# How to update TWRP from within TWRP?

Tags: updates, twrp, rom-update

I'm in TWRP after a factory reset and I'd like to avoid to install some OS to update TWRP with the [TWRP update app TWRP from within TWRP?

I have a Moto G2014 and previously had Cyanogenmod 13 installed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Downloading coming from the [list of devices](https://twrp.me/Devices/) allows to download a `.img` image which can be transferred via MTP-USB connection and installed after selecting `Images` in the `Install` file browser. When asked to select between boot and recovery partition select the recovery partition (selecting the boot partition has at least no effect and might be harmful).

It's possible to flash a newer version via `fastboot` as well.

Comment: (In newer versions of TWRP you get offered Boot, Recovery and System Image.)

Answer (score 4):

TWRP can be updated within TWRP recovery itself, by flashing the latest image.
Alternatively, TWRP can also be updated via Flashify and Official TWRP apps. It is a simple way to update without using a pc.

Refer here for detailed guide -[How to update TWRP to latest version without PC](https://web.archive.org/web/20180806225217/http://www.droidbro.com/how-to-update-twrp-recovery-to-latest-version-no-pc/).